# Remove old SSH session-configurations (for remote debug)

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

How can I remove old SSH session configurations?

Been looking in registry and %appdata% but couldn't find it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type in a dummy-server and the next dialog-box will give you the option:

[image]

Comment: Aggravating. It seems this no longer works in VS2022 17.6.4 (July 2023).

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2022, version 17.6.4 and later (July 2023), SSH information has been moved to the Options dialog.

`Tools -> Options -> Cross Platform -> Connection Manager`

Unfortunately, this little secret is buried in the Output window, the error dialog only tells you `SSH key exchange failed`. If this annoys you, too, please upvote my [request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Clarify-how-to-fix-obsolete-remote-debug/10410505) to improve the error message.